# single page site sticky nav: changing active state of content elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single page site with a fixed (sticky) sidebar navigation menu on the left and a main div with content. The main div is split into 5 sections, with numerous elements within each id.

I am trying to achieve a couple of interdependent/ dynamic state changes in relation to both the navigation menu **and** the elements in the main contents div, but I am struggling to get all parts of the equation to work. Please see my code below.

1. **When a menu item is selected**

a.) its state should change to ‘selected’; and

b) the page should smooth-scroll to the corresponding section id in the main div; and

c) the elements in the main div that correspond to the selected menu item should change state to ‘active’.

2. **When the user scrolls up and down the page:**

a.) the navigation should update itself based on the current section in view (‘selected’); and

b.) the elements in the main contents div should change state (‘active’) when they enter the centre of the viewport.

(I realise that points 1.c and 2.b are more or less interchangeable, but not sure which logic best to follow.)

From the above list, point 1 seems to work fine so far, but my code starts to fall apart when I try to update the navigation based on scroll position. I am hitting a roadblock with my limited javascript skills and would be very grateful for suggestions.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav_menu_item a').click(function(evt) {
    var selectedTab = $(this);
    var featureGroup = selectedTab.parents('.sidebar_nav_container');
    var allTabs = featureGroup.find('.nav_menu_item a');
    var allContent = featureGroup.find('.feature_box');

    // get the rel attribute to know what box we need to activate
    var rel = $(this).parent().attr('rel');

    // clear tab selections
    allTabs.removeClass('selected');
    selectedTab.addClass('selected');

    // make all boxes "in-active"
    $('.feature_box').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).removeClass('in-active');
    });

    //show what we need
    $('.feature_category_'+rel).addClass('active');

    // find correlated content
    var idx = selectedTab.index();
    var selectedContent = $(allContent);
    selectedContent.removeClass('in-active');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#"+rel).offset().top -90
    }, 800);

  });
});


$(document).ready(function () {

  var length = $('#sidebar_wrapper').height() - $('.sidebar_nav_container').height() + $('#sidebar_wrapper').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {

    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = $('.sidebar_nav_container').height() + 'px';

    if (scroll < $('#sidebar_wrapper').offset().top) {

      $('.sidebar_nav_container').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '0'
      });

    } else if (scroll > length) {

      $('.sidebar_nav_container').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': '0',
        'top': 'auto'
      });

    } else {

      $('.sidebar_nav_container').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '45px',
        'height': height

      });

    }
  });

});



$(document).ready(function () {

  (function highlightNav() {
      var prev; //keep track of previous selected link
      var isVisible= function(el){
          el = $(el);

          if(!el || el.length === 0){
              return false
          };

          var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
          var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

          var elemTop = el.offset().top;
          var elemBottom = elemTop + el.height();
          return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
      }

      $(window).scroll(function(){
          $('.sidebar_nav_container > .nav_menu_item a').each(function(index, el){
              el = $(el);
              if(isVisible(el.attr('href'))){
                  if(prev){
                      prev.removeClass('selected');
                  }
                  el.addClass('selected');
                  prev = el;

                  //break early to keep highlight on the first/highest visible element
                  //remove this you want the link for the lowest/last visible element to be set instead
                  return false;
              }
          });
      });

      //trigger the scroll handler to highlight on page load
      $(window).scroll();
  })();
 });
```

```css
.hidden {
 display:block;
 color: blue;
 }

.features_page {
    margin-top:12px;
    position: relative;
    }

.container {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-left:12px;
  padding-right:12px
  }

.container .features_public_content_container {
 height: 100% !important;
 position: relative;
 max-width:1200px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 font-size:12px;
 padding:auto;
 }

.col {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    }

.span_2 {
  width: 20%;
    }

.span_10 {
  width: 80%;
    }

#sidebar_wrapper {
    height: 100% !important;
    position: fixed;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 12px;
 }

#right {
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
 position: relative;
 }


.sidebar_nav_container {
     margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left
  }

.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item a {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 color:#1193f6 !important;
 text-align: left;
 line-height:40px;
 height:40px;
 padding-left: 24px;
 border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:500;
 overflow:hidden;
 cursor:pointer;
 position:relative
 }


.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item a .indicator {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 display:none;
 bottom:0;
 left: 0
 }

.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item a.indicator:hover {
 display:block;
 border-left:4px solid #d6ecfd;
 }

.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item a.selected {
 display:block;
 border-left:4px solid #1193f6;
 }


.feature_boxes_container {
 padding-bottom:12px;
 padding-top:12px;
 text-align: center !important;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 }

.feature_boxes_container .feature_box {
   float: none;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
  background:#fff;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  margin:12px;
  padding: 24px;
  vertical-align:top;
  -webkit-border-radius:2px;
  -moz-border-radius:2px;
  -ms-border-radius:2px;
  -o-border-radius:2px;
  border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  -ms-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  -o-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)
  }

.feature_boxes_container .feature_box.active {
  border: 2px solid #1193f6;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body id='public_layout' class='with_header'>

  <div class="layout_wrapper">

    <div class="features_page">

      <div class="container features_public_content_container">

        
        <div class="col span_2" id="sidebar_wrapper">

          <div class="sidebar_nav_container">

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_A selected" rel="A">
              <a href="#A" class="indicator">Features A</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_B" rel="B">
              <a href="#B" class="indicator">Features B</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_C" rel="C">
              <a href="#C" class="indicator">Features C</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_D" rel="D">
              <a href="#D" class="indicator">Features D</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_E" rel="E">
              <a href="#E" class="indicator">Features E</a>
            </div>
        
          </div> <!-- / .sidebar_nav_container -->
        
        </div> <!-- / #left-sidebar -->


        <div class="col span_10" id="right">
          
           <div class="feature_boxes_container">
            
             <!-- Features A -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active" id="A">Feature A-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-5</div>
           
             <!-- Features B -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active" id="B">Feature B-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-5</div>
             
             <!-- Features C -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active" id="C">Feature C-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-5</div>
           
             <!-- Features D -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active" id="D">Feature D-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-5</div>
             
    <!-- Features E -->

             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active" id="E">Feature E-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-5</div>            
            
            
            </div> <!-- /.feature_boxes_container -->

          </div> <!-- / #right -->
        
     </div> <!-- / .container .features_public_content_container -->

   </div> <!-- / .features_page -->

    </div> <!-- / .layout_wrapper -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is the jQuery code that finally made it work:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  $( ".feature_category" ).each(function() {
    var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top -180) {
      $('.nav_menu_item a.selected').removeClass("selected");
      $('.nav_menu_item a[href=\'#'+sectionID+'\']').parent().addClass("selected");
      $('.main_contents .feature_boxes_container .feature_category').removeClass('active');
      $('#'+sectionID+'').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});

// Cache selectors
var topMenu = $(".sidebar_nav_container"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight(),
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+36;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
  // Get container scroll position
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

  // Get id of current scroll item
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length-1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    menuItems
    .parent().removeClass("selected")
    .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("selected");
  });
});


$(document).ready(function () {

  var length = $('#sidebar_wrapper').height() - $('.sidebar_nav_container').height() + $('#sidebar_wrapper').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {

    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = $('.sidebar_nav_container').height() + 'px';

    if (scroll < $('#sidebar_wrapper').offset().top -90) {

      $('.sidebar_nav_container').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '0'
      });

    } else if (scroll > length) {

      $('.sidebar_nav_container').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': '0',
        'top': 'auto'
      });

    } else {

      $('.sidebar_nav_container').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '60px',
        'height': height
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I managed to cobble this together based on other stackoverflow answers, as well as some helpful pointers here. It's probably the worst kind of spaghetti code that you've ever seen, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured I would chime in and maybe offer a little better setup.  With your demo javascript I can only assume that you are going to have a header and footer and you want your menu to affix and then stop at a certain point but I'm not entirely sure because in your demo this is not the case and you just have a normal fixed menu.  So I have added the affix style where the menu will fix once you have scrolled past the header and then stop when it reaches the footer. Then the active classes of the items in your main content and the navigation will change upon scrolling.  So what I suggest is using jquery each function and then wrap your items in a span and give that span a class of features-category and an id to this span.  Then each time the window scrolls to this span you can fire a function changing classes.  The only thing is that if 2 sections are occupying the same line then you will have issues so I suggest making your feature boxes have a percentage width and set the percentage to the minimum amount of boxes so if you have a min of 4 feature boxes per section set the width to 25%.  Then you can use media queries to make them bigger at smaller screens.

Here is a working fiddle demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/n5rLra8x/)

So your html markup will look similar to this:

```
  <div class='pub_site_nav'>
    <div class="container">
         Page navigation menu
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /.container .pub_site_nav -->

  <div class="features_page">

      <div class="story_section_container">
           <div class="container">
                Hero section
           </div>
      </div><!-- /.container .pub_site_nav -->


      <div class="main_contents">
           <div class="container">


                <div id="sidebar_wrapper">
                     <div class="sidebar_nav_container">
                          <div class="nav_menu_item selected"><a href="#A">Features A</a></div>
                          <div class="nav_menu_item"><a href="#B">Features B</a></div>
                          <div class="nav_menu_item"><a href="#C">Features C</a></div>
                          <div class="nav_menu_item"><a href="#D">Features D</a></div>
                          <div class="nav_menu_item"><a href="#E">Features E</a></div>
                     </div><!-- /.sidebar_nav_container-->
                </div><!-- /.#sidebar_wrapper-->

                <div class="feature_boxes_container">

                     <span class="feature_category active" id="A">
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature A-1</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature A-2</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature A-3</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature A-4</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature A-5</div>
                          </div>
                    </span>

                    <span class="feature_category" id="B">
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature B-1</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature B-2</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature B-3</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature B-4</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature B-5</div>
                          </div>
                    </span>

                    <span class="feature_category" id="C">
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-1</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-2</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-3</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-4</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-5</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-6</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature C-7</div>
                          </div>
                    </span>

                    <span class="feature_category" id="D">
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature D-1</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature D-2</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature D-3</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature D-4</div>
                          </div>
                    </span>

                    <span class="feature_category" id="E">
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature E-1</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature E-2</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature E-3</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature E-4</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature E-5</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="feature_box_wrapper">
                               <div class="feature_box">Feature E-6</div>
                          </div>
                    </span>


                </div><!-- /.feature_boxes_container-->

           </div><!-- /.container-->
      </div><!-- /.container .main_contents -->
      <div class="random_content" style="height:800px;background:#111;"></div>

      <div class="public_footer">
           <div class="container">
                Footer
           </div>
      </div> <!-- / .container .public_footer -->
  </div><!-- /.features_page -->
```

And then your Jquery will looks something like this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    $( ".feature_category" ).each(function() {
        var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - 220 ) {
           $('.nav_menu_item.selected').removeClass("selected");
           $('.nav_menu_item a[href=\'#'+sectionID+'\']').parent().addClass("selected");
           $('.feature_category').removeClass('active');
           $('#'+sectionID+'').addClass('active');
        }
    });
    /*Affix code*/
    var contentTop = $("#sidebar_wrapper").offset().top - 68;
    var footerTop = $(".random_content").offset().top - $('.sidebar_nav_container').outerHeight() - 65;
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= contentTop) {
        $( '.sidebar_nav_container' ).addClass("fixed");
    }else{
        $( '.sidebar_nav_container' ).removeClass("fixed");
    }
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= footerTop) {
       $( '.sidebar_nav_container' ).addClass("absolute_bottom");
    }else{
      $( '.sidebar_nav_container' ).removeClass("absolute_bottom");
    }
});
$( document ).on( "click", ".sidebar_nav_container a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var sectionID = $(this).attr("href");
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionID).offset().top - 200
    }, 800);
});
```

I added some comments in the jquery code where you can remove the menu affix code if you are not trying to use it.  Then you can just use a normal position fixed css to your menu.

And finally here is the css you would use:

```
body,html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
/*easier to have your container with margin and not padding that way your element is actually in that position and not padding to that position*/
.container {
  margin:0 80px;
  position:relative;
}
.pub_site_nav {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:10;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  height:68px;
  line-height:64px;
  background:yellow;
}
.features_page{
  margin-top:65px;
}
.features_page .story_section_container {
  background-color:#888;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  padding-top:72px;
  text-align:left
}
/*Better to have a fixed width for your sidebar that way everything will work properly when your sidebar goes fixed because you need to account for your .container margin once it is in fixed position you can do it with a percentage if you use css calc but it has less browser compatibility also your main_contents should not have a max-width because when the sidebar goes fixed it will be in the wrong position if the screen goes above the max-width of the container*/
#sidebar_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 200px;
  background:orange;
}
.sidebar_nav_container {
  padding: 24px 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.sidebar_nav_container.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:68px;
  left:80px;
}
.sidebar_nav_container.absolute_bottom{
  position:absolute;
  top:auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}
.sidebar_nav_item{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item a {
  text-align: left;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 24px;
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:500;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  /*so nav item doesn't jump on hover*/
  border:4px solid transparent;
}

.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item a:hover {
  border-left:4px solid #d6ecfd;
}

.sidebar_nav_container .nav_menu_item.selected a {
  border-left:4px solid #1193f6;
}

.feature_boxes_container{
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding:45px 0 80px 0;
  margin-left:200px;
  /*The Following 2 lines removes the whitespace from feature box wrapper so they will align with a width of 25%*/
  font-size:0;
  zoom: 1;
}
.feature_box_wrapper{
  width:25%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.feature_boxes_container .feature_box {
  text-align: center;
  background:#fff;
  margin:10px;
  padding: 24px;
  height:100px;
  /*so everything aligns properly and doesn't jump when activated*/
  border:2px solid transparent;
  font-size:12px;
}
.feature_boxes_container .feature_category.active .feature_box {
  border: 1px solid red
}
.features_page .public_footer {
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: green;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1049px){
  .feature_box_wrapper{width: 50%; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .container{margin:0 10px; }
  #sidebar_wrapper{width: 125px; }
  .sidebar_nav_container{width:125px; }
  .sidebar_nav_container.fixed{left:10px; }
  .sidebar_nav_container.absolute_bottom{left:0; }
  .feature_boxes_container{margin-left:125px; }
  .feature_box_wrapper{width: 100%; }
}
```

The css may be a little messy as I just threw it together pretty quick but I figured you can mess with it and make your own layout but this should get you started.

If you have any questions feel free to comment me and I hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice!! I have upvoted your answer because your demo fiddle does exactly what I have been trying to achieve. Simple, elegant, effective. Also, you were absolutely right with your assumption about the header and footer, didn't bear that in mind, so thanks for including the affix code. I am still struggling with the markup and the CSS (trying to adapt it to my existing setup). I'll mark the post as answered once I have everything fixed. I might post another comment if I don't manage to get it to work. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Glad to help.  I know that it may be easier to give the side nav a fixed width and then remove the width percentage from the main content and then you should be able to pretty much copy and paste it into any layout but not sure because I don't know what your layout is.  Here is an example of that.and fixed a couple of css things  https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/k6e6vg65/ Sometimes percentages can be kind of tricky to mess with and your side nav doesn't really need to be a percentage anyways.  But feel free to comment me if you have any trouble.

Comment: So I noticed that this method is a little buggy when at wider screens and there are 2 id's occupying the same line.  I will try and work out a better solutoin and update my answer a little later

Comment: I’m struggling and not making sense anymore. I tried to de-construct your code and put it back together to fit with my HTML and CSS, but that didn’t lead me anywhere and it ended up a complete mess. I’ve tried pretty much everything I could think of and hitting a roadblock now. Here is a fiddle with the complete (and simplified) markup, as well as the css https://jsfiddle.net/32k_/gko1d76k/1/. I would be very grateful if you could give me some pointers as to how to tweak your jquery code so that it works with my markup tags and css. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, so my previous fiddle was a mess – I tried to clean up a bit, see https://jsfiddle.net/gko1d76k/7/ What puzzles me is the fact that I cannot get the fiddle to work properly, no matter what I do. I have copy-pasted the markup etc directly from my files. My local version runs just fine, but I cannot reproduce the result in fiddle. Any clues? – The only thing that is missing now is binding the scroll position to the sidebar menu navigation tabs via the 'selected' class. The rest of the jQuery code seems to work just fine (at least locally). Could you help me figure out how to make this work?

Comment: So it probably won't work in the fiddle because you need to add a link to jquery in the external resources on the left.  But your markup and css is kind of messed up so I fixed everything here https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/ctfar9pz/ the only problem with this is if 2 ids are occupying the same line then you will have problems so I made another demo with percentage widths for your feature boxes here https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/n5rLra8x/  I have also made this demo responsive.  Read the comments that I left in the css section of both and I will update the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you @Drinkin People, I have read all your comments in detail. This has been very instructive, and also helped me fix a few more issues that I encountered in my code. Learned some new things today, much appreciated! (p.s. Also, sorry about the fiddle setup mistakes!)

Comment: ... one last question, @Drinkin People: your jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/n5rLra8x, lines 64-76. It's a minor detail, but I've also been trying to eliminate the nav_menu_item jumps on hover, and you applied a transparent border (same 4px width as the "selected" state) to solve the issue (which works, of course). However, I am trying to find a way to keep the "static" 1px grey left border. Is there a way to keep the nav_menu_items from jumping on hover, while still keeping the <border-left: 1px solid #efefef> on <display: block>? Or would I have to put the grey left border into a separate div for that?

Comment: You can put it on the nav_menu_item that is wrapping the <a> tag.  I spelled it wrong in the demo but I fixed it and updated both of the fiddles so you can check it again.

Comment: Thank you, that was kind of obvious, been staring at my screen for too long. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Lets check some part of your question. Will update for full answer

```js
   $(function() {
     $('.nav_menu_item a').click(function(evt) {
       var selectedTab = $(this);
       var featureGroup = selectedTab.parents('.sidebar_nav_container');
       var allTabs = featureGroup.find('.nav_menu_item a');
       var allContent = featureGroup.find('.feature_box');
   
       // get the rel attribute to know what box we need to activate
       var rel = $(this).parent().attr('rel');
   
       // clear tab selections
       allTabs.removeClass('selected');
       selectedTab.addClass('selected');
   
       // make all boxes "in-active"
       $('.feature_box').each(function() {
         $(this).removeClass('active');
         $(this).removeClass('in-active');
       });
   
       //show what we need
       $('.feature_category_'+rel).addClass('active');
   
       // find correlated content
       var idx = selectedTab.index();
       var selectedContent = $(allContent);
       selectedContent.removeClass('in-active');
       
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#"+rel).offset().top
       }, 2000);
   
     });
   });
   
   
   $('a').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top -90
     }, 800);
   });
```

```css
   .clearfix:after {
      content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      height: 0;
      clear: both;
   }
   .hidden {
    display:block;
    color: blue;
    }
   
   .container {
     margin:0 auto;
     padding-left:80px;
     padding-right:80px
     }
   
   .features_public_content_container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:0 40px
    }
   
   
   #left_sidebar {
       height: 100% !important;
       width: 25% !important;
       position: fixed;
    float: left
    }
   
   #right {
    height: auto;
    max-width:75% !important;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    }
   
   
   .features_page {
       margin-top:12px;
       position: relative;
    }
   
   .features_page .sidebar_nav_container {
    margin: auto;
       position: relative;
    float: left
    }
   
   .features_page .sidebar_nav_container .feature_tab {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    color:#1193f6 !important;
    text-align: left;
    line-height:40px;
    height:40px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    font-size:12px;
    border-left:2px solid #efefef !important;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:500;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative
    }
   
   .features_page .sidebar_nav_container .feature_tab .indicator {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:none;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0
    }
   
   .features_page .sidebar_nav_container .feature_tab:hover .indicator {
    display:block;
    border-left:4px solid #d6ecfd
    }
   
   .features_page .sidebar_nav_container .feature_tab.selected .indicator {
    display:block;
    border-left:4px solid #1193f6;
    }
   
   
   .features_page .feature_boxes_container {
    padding-bottom:12px;
    padding-top:12px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    }
   
   .features_page .feature_boxes_container .feature_box {
     background:#fff;
     display:inline-block;
     height:150px;
     width:60px;
     margin:12px;
     padding: 24px;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:top;
     -webkit-border-radius:2px;
     -moz-border-radius:2px;
     -ms-border-radius:2px;
     -o-border-radius:2px;
     border-radius:2px;
     -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
     -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
     -ms-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
     -o-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
     box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)
     }
   
   .features_page .feature_boxes_container .feature_box.active {
     border: 2px solid #1193f6;
     }
   
   .features_page .feature_boxes_container .feature_box.in-active .feature_overview_icon {
    color: #363636;
   }
   
   
   .nav_menu_item {
    margin: 8px 0;
   }
   .nav_menu_item a{padding: 5px;}
   .nav_menu_item .selected {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    color: white;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="layout_wrapper">

    <div class="features_page">

      <div class="container features_public_content_container clearfix">

        
        <div class="col span_2 clearfix" id="left_sidebar">

          <div class="sidebar_nav_container">

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_A selected" rel="A">
              <a href="#A" class="indicator">Features A</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_B" rel="B">
              <a href="#B" class="indicator">Features B</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_C" rel="C">
              <a href="#C" class="indicator">Features C</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_D" rel="D">
              <a href="#D" class="indicator">Features D</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav_menu_item feature_category_E" rel="E">
              <a href="#E" class="indicator">Features E</a>
            </div>
        
          </div> <!-- / .sidebar_nav_container -->
        
        </div> <!-- / #left-sidebar -->


        <div class="col span_10" id="right">
          
           <div class="feature_boxes_container">
            
             <!-- Features A -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active" id="A">Feature A-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_A active">Feature A-5</div>
           
             <!-- Features B -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active" id="B">Feature B-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_B in-active">Feature B-5</div>
             
             <!-- Features C -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active" id="C">Feature C-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_C in-active">Feature C-5</div>
           
             <!-- Features D -->
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active" id="D">Feature D-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_D in-active">Feature D-5</div>
             
    <!-- Features E -->

             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active" id="E">Feature E-1</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-2</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-3</div>
 
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-4</div>
             
             <div class="feature_box feature_category_E in-active">Feature E-5</div>            
            
            
            </div> <!-- /.feature_boxes_container -->

          </div> <!-- / #right -->
        
     </div> <!-- / .container .features_public_content_container -->

   </div> <!-- / .features_page -->

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @PHPExpert! Thank you very much for posting and for pointing me in the right direction. This definitely helps! (I can see that I made some basic mistakes in my original CSS and jQuery, so thanks a lot for the edit.) I have already updated the original fiddle, so part 1 of the equation is now working correctly. I'd be very grateful for your thoughts about applying the scrollSpy-type effect that I outlined under point 2) in my question. I attempted to adapt the scrollSpy plugin for the purposes of my page, but it just won't work. Should I post my "scrollSpy code" anyhow? Please advise.

Comment: Most welcome 32k_. If you feel answer is useful then do upvote and accept it. Regarding scrollSpy plugin, I am not much familiar about it. But do add it so it will help more to resolve issue.

Comment: I upvoted the answer as it solves part of the issue. I have also updated the fiddle now to include the markup and jQuery for the scrollspy effect. For reference, please see: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp Also, this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145609/complex-active-state-navigation-on-single-page-website?rq=1 My code is not working at the moment. I am not sure I am initializing the scrollspy correctly ... and also, not sure the html markup is correct. Let me know if you have suggestions. Thanks again!